# Problem connecting to ssh server that is behind another ssh server in nautilus

Tags: networking, server, nautilus, ssh

So I have this school server that I am trying to connect to via nautilus. In terminal it's all easy but I want to be able to open it also in nautilus.

In terminal my way of doing it looks like this:

```
ssh myUser@my.server.com
```

Now that I am connected in there, I can do `ssh myUser2.my.server2.com` inside of that server to connect to server2.  I canoot connect to server 2 directly. It has to be done like I do it right now.

So right now I can only get a connection to the first server in nautilus by typing `ssh://myUser@my.server.com`

But how do I connect to the server2 from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your first SSH server (`my.server.com`) supports [TCP Port Forwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding), you can forward a port on your local system (`localhost`) to `my.server2.com` via `my.server.com`:

```
ssh -fNL 2022:my.server2.com:22 myUser@my.server.com
```

This will forward port 2022 on `localhost` to port 22 on `my.server2.com`. Then you can connect directly to the second server:

```
ssh myUser2@localhost:2022
```

In Nautilus, you can connect using `ssh://myUser2@localhost:2022`.

---

The `-fN` flags send SSH to the background, and creates a problem in closing it. There are three ways out:

#### Autoclose

```
ssh -fNL 2022:my.server2.com:22 myUser@my.server.com sleep 10
```

Now connect using Nautilus before the sleep command finishes executing (10 seconds). The connection will be kept alive as long as Nautilus is connected. When done, disconnect from Nautilus and the connection will be stopped.

#### Let the command wait for input

```
ssh -tL 2022:my.server2.com:22 myUser@my.server.com 'read -p"Press Enter to exit: "'
```

The [`read`](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html) command will wait for input. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you're done to close the connection.

#### Look up the connection process and kill it

```
pgrep -fa fNL
```

This will show you all processes which have `fNL` in the command line (there should only be your SSH connection process).
Either [`kill`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/kill.1.html) the PID of the right process if there are more than one, or use [`pkill`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pgrep.1.html) if there is only one process:
    pkill -f fNL
This is pretty much the only option for connections that have already been established using `-fN`.

#### Run no command, and exit as usual

```
ssh -L 2022:my.server2.com:22 myUser@my.server.com
```

This will open a normal shell, from which you can exit as you normally do.

Comment: And after I am done, how do I close this port again?

Comment: @Kaspar I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer! This solution works very well for me.